# Express - call require once for many routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My project directory looks something like this:

```
MyProject
    -app.js
    -routes
        -routeone
        -routetwo
```

Inside of my app.js file it looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var routeone = require('./routes/routeone');
var routetwo = require('./routes/routetwo');

app.use('/routeone', routeone);
app.use('/routetwo', routetwo);
.
.
.
```

Each route file  looks something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.param) {
        //no parameter was provided
    } else {
        //there was a parameter provided
    }
});
```

module.exports = router;

As you can see I have a dependency on the bodyparser module. I need to call this module in every route and specify the options for this.I may have many more routes in the future. I would like to avoid specifying this in every single route file because say I need to change the `extended:true` in the future I will have to go to every file and change this. I would prefer to have this in one location. I tried adding this to to the app.js file, but then urlencodedParser can;t be found inside of the route files. I also assume this has a performance hit since every route needs to load this module.

Comment: when you tried to add the body parser in the app.js, how did you do it? and what error did you get?

Comment: Can you just put the body-parser middleware on the `app` object in just one place and not on every router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some choices:

**1) Put the body-parser middleware on the `app` object** in just one place rather than on every individual route.

**2) Create a new module that extracts the common code** and creates a router for you with the router middleware already on it:

```
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});    
router.use(urlencodedParser);
module.exports = router;
```

And, then use that new module to create each of your routers.  If/when you need to change `extended: false`, you can then just change it in one place.

**3) Create a new module that just gets you a common `urlencodedParser` middleware function** that you can use in each of your routers:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});    
module.exports = urlencodedParser;
```

And, then require that into each module and use the imported parser in each router.

Comment: thanks for the reply! All of these seem to work. Is one better more efficient than the others?

Comment: @user2924127 - They are each different levels of granularity so you should select the one that fits what you need.  The first runs the `urlencodedParser` as global middleware for every single route.  If that's what you need, then that is the simplest and saves the most code.  The second runs it for every single route on a given router, allowing you to have some whole routers that don't use that middleware.  The third allows you to select exactly which routes in which router have this middleware - the most flexible, but the least code savings.

Comment: Sorry, now that I am actually coding this I am having problem understanding.  I want to definitely use the first option so it applies application wide. So lets say I have a module called myModule. How do I now use this then in another module? So in my app.js file I put app.use(myModule()). Inside of myModule is a function called createUser(). Now I am in my routeone.js file and I want to access createUser() how would I do this?

Comment: @user2924127 - Well, now you're asking a bit of a different question.  I can't answer that without seeing actual code you're trying to use.  I believe I answered the question you asked.  If you don't understand something about that, then please tell me exactly what about your original question you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just have to variables: 
`var urlencodedParserF = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});`

`var urlencodedParserT = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
});`